# How a rotating conducting spherical shell, which is uniformly charged, keeps the magnetic field zero inside it?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, conductors

Assume that a uniformly charged spherical metallic shell starts to rotate around one of its axes of symmetry reaching a constant angular velocity of $\omega$. Since the magnetic field is zero everywhere inside the shell before the rotation, it is anticipated that the magnetic field would maintain a null value inside the shell during the rotation. Otherwise, if the magnetic field changes from a zero value to, say, a constant nonzero value, we have $\partial B/\partial t$ inside the metallic sphere, which, in turn, produces an electric field inside the shell, whereas we know that the appearance of any electric field inside a conductive material is forbidden.

On the other hand, if we assume that the magnetic field has a zero value inside the shell during the rotation, and yet has a nonzero value outside it, it would be odd how the magnetic field lines make a closed pattern (${\rm div}\,B=0$). It is also possible that if there exists a magnetic field on the outside, the Lorentz force accumulates the charges towards one of the poles, however, I cannot understand how this can nullify the magnetic field inside and outside the sphere since the repulsive Coulomb's force does not allow the charges to be gathered on a mathematical (dimensionless) point on one of the poles.

Comment: An electric field inside a conductive shell is not forbidden. It simply comes with a current through the shell.